# Passing a HashMap argument to Scala using spark-submit

Tags: scala, hashmap, nosuchmethoderror, spark-submit

I am defining a main object with hashmap as argument;

```
def main(args: Map [ String, Any ]  )
: Unit = {

    val v_COUNTRY_CODE =args("CTRY_CD").toString
    val v_REPORTING_DATE = args("REP_DT").toString
    val v_WorkSpaces = args("WS_NM").toString
    println("v_COUNTRY_CODE"+ v_COUNTRY_CODE)
    println("v_REPORTING_DATE"+ v_REPORTING_DATE)
    println("v_WorkSpaces"+ v_WorkSpaces)
    println("Yes I am done")
    sys.exit()
}
```

How can I pass a `Hashmap` argument while running through `spark-submit`:

`spark-submit --verbose --name SAMPLE --master yarn --deploy-mode client  --class com.scb.transformations.factScbB3dqBalancesFload /CTRLFW/btrapp_nas/RUBIK/hdpbatch/appscripts/../lib/rubikDashboard.jar { "HIVE_SCHEMA" -> "Test"}`

Throws an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.scb.transformations.factScbB3dqBalancesFload.main([Ljava.lang.String;)

Answer (score 0):

The main() method in Scala requires the argument of type Array[String]. So, you can only pass space-separated string as arguments via CLI. If you further wish to use the arguments as map, then you can simply choose a separator for key and values; split them in your code and create a Scala map. e.g. if your separator was '=' then you could pass CLI arguments simply as

HIVE_SCHEMA=Test SomeOtherParam=SomeValue

And in your code you could create a map like

val confMap = args.map( x => (x.split("=")(0), x.split("=")(1)) ).toMap